# Task crash while trying to search folder without permission

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my function that get `IEnumerable<string> source` and search all the files inside this path:

```
public void search()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_source,
            new ParallelOptions
           {
               MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 //limit number of parallel threads here 
           },
        file =>
        {
            FileChecker fileChecker = new FileChecker();
            string result = fileChecker.check(file);
            if (result != null)
                OnFileAddEvent(result);
        });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }).ContinueWith
        (t =>
        {
            OnFinishSearchEvent();
        }
, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
);
}

  public void search2()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var filtered = _source.AsParallel()
                                   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
                                   .Where(file =>
                                   {
                                       try
                                       {
                                           FileChecker fileChecker = new FileChecker();
                                           string result = fileChecker.check(file);
                                           if (result != null)
                                               OnFileAddEvent(result);
                                           return true;
                                       }
                                       catch (Exception)
                                       {
                                           return false;
                                       }
                                   });
        return filtered.ToList();
    }).ContinueWith
     (t =>
     {
         OnFinishSearchEvent();
     }
     , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
     );
}
```

Comment: what will happen if you put the try-catch into the lamda statement block?

Comment: You are not catching what the task does -> move your try-catch inside of the lambda.

Comment: I suspect actually that you are trying to access an STA object in an MTA thread....

Comment: You must not enumerate into a folder you do not have permissions for. A try-catch statement will not stop this from happening. You cannot use the try-catch statement to restart the enumeration either.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of Multithreading and Exception Handling.

Exception handling in .net typically starts with a managed exception being thrown. This then causes the .net VM to then walk up the call stack until it finds an appropriate try catch block.

In this case the `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)`, is a wrapper to push onto the thread pool work described in the `Action` delegate. The top of the call stack would in this case be the `Action` delegate described in...

```
file =>
      {
            // check my file before adding to my Listbox
      }
```

So when an exception bubbles up...nothing is "up" the call stack to catch it.

The solution then is either to, as others have described, add a root level try catch in the delegate you pass into the `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)` method.

More generally one would normally add a OnError continuation on the `Task` returned by the `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)`...however I would also add that I would be worried that this entire method is highly flawed, as none of the worker threads should be able to add to the `ListBox`. The `ListBox` should ONLY ever be accessed by the STA thread that constructed it.

Ultimately I would change the entire method to the following...

```
public void search()
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {

        var filtered = source.AsParallel()
                                   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
                                   .Where(file =>
        {
            try
            {
                //Some filter function...
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return filtered.ToList();
    }).ContinueWith
    (t =>
    {
        foreach(var result in t.Result)
        {
            MyListBox.Add(result);
        }
        OnFinishSearchEvent();
    }
    , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
    );


}
```

Comment: the file that i check before adding open new wireshark process so i want the option to limit the number of open processes like i do before, how can i do it ?

Comment: BTW i am add file into my listbox via another class, inside this function i am send the file to another class that open Wireshark process ans check if the file is valid (thas why i want to limit the current number of processes) and i it does it fire an event to my main form with the file name and from the main form another function add this file

Comment: Also its must be noted that exceptions are expensive. If possible I would try to find a method of checking for permissions first...
Not to mention in general it makes debugging difficult (since I find it useful to have "Break on All CLR Exceptions on", as you tend to be able to fix problems as they occur as opposed to symptomatically).

Comment: Firstly, I noted that you add everything onto a `System.Collection.Generic.List`. These are not thread safe. There is a chance that have all the different threads adding at the same time will cause problems. By using PLinq to create the list you avoid this issue. Secondly by limiting the number of cross thread posting, to a single List, rather than each item, you reduce the overhead.

Comment: compilation error that Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<string,int,bool>' (the variable file marked)

Comment: Thanks, and what need to be inside the second lambda expression ? (i moved the foreach)

Comment: No idea, since I don't know how you changed it.

Comment: See my update...what are the differences between your function (search2) and mind (search) ?

Answer (score 0):

You must catch what is inside of the Task:

```
public void search()
{
    try
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try{
            Parallel.ForEach(source,
                             new ParallelOptions
                             {
                                 MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 //limit number of parallel threads here 
                             },
                             file =>
                             {
                                // check my file before adding to my Listbox
                             });
            }).ContinueWith
                (t =>
                {
                    OnFinishSearchEvent();
                }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```